# There is no more app.module.ts in new Angular Asp.net Core new update

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core

What's up developers please am having a serious issue with the new Template for Angular Asp.net Core because when i try to download This
it downloaded the new template

```html
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

but when looking at the Client folder in the app folder there was no more app.module.ts. it was replaced with app.module.shared, app.module.client app.module.server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud99X.png)

Please i would like if i can get any help because i don't know how to use this new components. if anyone have idea of how to use this new components

Thanks.